# Does an instantiation of a derived class allocate memory for private members of base class?

Tags: c++

I guess the topic is all I need to ask. A little explanation around the topic would be nice. Please clear some questions like why or why not?

Example:

```
class A {
 private:
  int a;
};

class B : A {
 int b;
};

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
 B *p = new B(); // Does this allocate memory for a?
}
```

Comment: Yes it does. It allocates an `A` sub-object.

Comment: @juanchopanza don't want to be picky, but why did you put that in a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: sizeof() will show that B is at least the size of 2 ints, thus answering your question.

Comment: @SebastianDressler the question asks for an explanation. I felt too lazy to write an essay right now.

Comment: @juanchopanza I think I can live with that ;)

Comment: Access modifiers are used at compile-time only. They are not evaluated at run-time. Class layout is not controlled by access modifiers, either. The same rules apply, regardless of access modifiers: The compiler will allocate memory for all sub-objects and base class sub-objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. A class object contains all of its direct non-static data members, and those of any base-class sub-objects. Access specifiers make no difference; they merely restrict where names can be used.

Comment: Thanks. A few information about the internals of inheritance would be fine too.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean with *allocate*: it does *not* do a heap allocation or something. A derived object will contain the members inherited from the base. That is all base classes of a derived class can be seen as subobjects. The derived class objects will contain all these subobjects and will also make sure that they are properly constructed/destructed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will allocate memory for A also.

Because when you inherit a `class` from another class and when you create the `object` of derived class, Complier will allocate memory equal to size of derived class+base class,so that there would be `no loss of data.` 
As `base class members` are also accessible from `derived class.`

Comment: Beware though: "accessible" might be a bit misleading here.

Comment: I have use word 'ACCESSIBLE' because no matter what's the access level of a member in base class,You **CAN ACCESS private,protected members** in derived class 'directly or indirectly' irrespective of inheriting specifier.